# Console Appication does not get arguments that contains $ sign when runnning from PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, console, command-line-arguments

I am trying to write a console app which will expect 7 command line arguments. The 4th argument is for password which I won't have any control over it. Passwords can contain $ sign.

Here is my simple code with just 1 argument for testing purposes that I call from PowerShell:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(args[0].Length);

}
```

if I run `program.exe abc$def` I get 
`abc` 
`3`

`$def` doesn't appear.

`program.exe "abc$edf"` doesn't change the end result. I get `abc` only

`program.exe "abc$\edf"` (without quotes as well) gives `abc$\def`

Any idea why and how to fix this?

Comment: Can't repro on my machine. Are you running it from a standard command window? What happens if you set the Command line in the Debug tab on the Project properties?

Comment: I was running from PowerShell window. I tried on CMD window and there is no problem :( Thanks for shedding some lights.

Comment: Looks useful. I've updated your post to explicitly mention PowerShell - see if edit matches your intentions. Also consider adding how to pass $ in case of PowerShell to your answer (and don't forget to accept it unless someone comes up with better one).

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I was running the program on `PowerShell window` instead of `CMD window`. `$` sign is special for `PowerShell`. That's why argument string was getting chopped off.

Comment: You just need to encode the $, try replace $'s with `$ before you send to command line exe.

Comment: $ is the start of a variable name, so it probably thinks $edf is a variable which a value of null

Comment: @Ryios You mean "escape" the `$` character. Yeah that's the ticket - `$.